# Travis build pipeline with snapshots

Tags: travis-ci

How to make build such that after project A finishes , it starts second project B. But in B project it also need to update the version which was created after A build. How to create build pipeline with snapshots builds.

Any example of the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not do any sort of pipeline in Travis in the way you described.

A **first solution** to achieve your goal is to configure (again) the build of your project A in the *install:* section of the *.travis* file of your project B. This will clone your project A each time the project B is built and process a redundant build.

An **other solution** is to upload the resulting build of the project A on a distant server and then download it when the project B is built, but this requires a distant server.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible now, although you will have to roll some scripts and set up quite a bit of configuration (as well as rely on a binary repository).

1. Set up and use Artifactory to host what you end up building from project A, see: https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/
2. Next, you'll want to use a Travis CI API that's in beta (currently, as of Nov 2016): https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds to trigger a build of your second project

The way this would work is to capture metadata (version, artifact name, whatever you need in order to run/trigger build B with A's produced artifacts) and send that as part of the `POST` to trigger build B.  Build B can then run a full build and pull whatever build A pushed to Artifactory as a dependency.

Between the two of those, you should be able to do this.